# How can I merge files from one branch to another branch in git?

Tags: git, github

I am using forked repository of `MainRepo`.in my forked repository I have a branch name as `Demo2`.In this branch I have 2 files names are `file1`and `file2`.

Know I want to merge total files from `Demo2` to `mergeTesting`.for that purpose,I created a new `mergeTesting`branch.for this purpose I ran the following commands

```
 I/Github/MainRepo[master]> git branch mergeTesting
 I/Github/MainRepo[master]> git checkout mergeTesting
 I/Github/MainRepo[mergeTesting]> git fetch origin
 I/Github/MainRepo[mergeTesting]> git merge origin/Demo2
 I/Github/MainRepo[mergeTesting]>git push --set-upstream origin mergeTesting
```

successfully,merging was completed and also pushed to my forked repository.

Know I want to delete entire files from the `mergeTesting`branch.for that purpose I ran the following command

```
     I/Github/MainRepo[mergeTesting]> git rm 
     I/Github/MainRepo[mergeTesting]> git push origin
```

successfully,deleting completed and pushed to my forked repository.

know, in my `mergeTesting` branch their is no files.

after sometime I want to merge files from  `Demo2` to `mergeTesting`.for that purpose I ran the following commands.

```
 I/Github/MainRepo[mergeTesting]> git fetch origin
 I/Github/MainRepo[mergeTesting]> git merge origin/Demo2
```

but know,it shows Already up-to-date,but If I ran the follwing command it doesn't shows any files.

```
 I/Github/MainRepo[mergeTesting]> ls
```

How can I merge files in second time.

can anyone help me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing the *exact* sequence of commands that you executed, it is a bit difficult to tell what you've done wrong.

However, it sounds to me like might have forgotten to "git checkout mergeTesting" before you started changing stuff.  Or maybe your "push" didn't do anything.

I suggest that you repeat exactly the steps that you performed before, keeping a copy of the exact commands and the output.  Then Edit this Question, and cut-and-paste the details into it.

Comment: I modified my question can you check it once